# UX/UI Documentation

Tags: mobile, documentation

In the next few weeks I'll be working on a project that teaches students how to program and design apps for Android Wear, tablets, and TVs. I'll be there as a UI and UX consultant, and will have about 14 apps to create UX or UI for them.
I have good skills in terms of making wireframes, creating/testing flows, and making high fidelity UI's, but I'm not so experienced in creating documentation of this process.
Does anyone know of some readily available papers documenting the process of UX testing for Android(or iOS) apps that I could read? Or can you point out some good articles describing what should be in such documents?

Thank you.

Comment: There is no 'one process'. It's going to really depend on the particulars of the project.

Comment: Wireframes are documentation. They document the design decisions you've made about what the project should include and how it should work. (Flow diagrams are too.) What other documents are you concerned about?

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, the best set of UX docs is

- Job stories
- Wireframes / mocks
- A prototype or flow diagram (or both)

The old days of writing a novel about the experience variations and meticulous interaction specification are (mostly) gone.

Comment: I think there's probably a lot of teams out there who are working on UX Design-related activities, who are still hook for delivering long spec docs and screens and screens of wireframes and mockups, because it's not their working practices that drive production, but rather those of their Engineering or Product Management department. UXD goes almost hand in glove with approaches like Agile, and Lean, but that's not worth much when you're working waterfall style on long projects.

Answer (score 1):

usability.gov is a great starting point for students to learn about usability testing in general and required documents that will apply not only to android platform but best practices that can be applied to all.

http://www.usability.gov/what-and-why/usability-evaluation.html

Scott Klemer's Coursera HCI class also documents such general testing requirements well in his lectures and provides a great blueprint starting point for teaching: 
https://www.coursera.org/learn/human-computer-interaction

For Android specifics, I would look at material design guideline's design principles and basically make a heuristic checklist out of such and have students rank how well such apps meet such criteria. 
More about heuristic evaluations: 
http://www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/

Answer (score 0):

it would be a good idea to make a good article | document for your Purpose with  :

http://studio.uxpin.com/ebooks/guide-to-ux-design-process-and-documentation

http://www.theuxbookmark.com/2010/08/ux-articles-and-research-papers/creative-design/a-monster-list-of-ui-guidelines-style-guides/